# UIPrintPageRenderer how to switch between US-Letter and DIN-A4 format

Tags: ios, swift, uiprintpagerenderer, uiprintformatter

I tried to implement a custom PDF-Renderer, inherited from UIPrintPageRenderer. My problem ist that the output-size of the PDF is 215,9 x 279,4 mm. But the correct DIN A4 dimensions i need are 210 x 297 mm. Obviously im getting the size of a US-Letter instead of the DIN A4. How can i change it to DIN A4?

```
...
class PDFRenderer: UIPrintPageRenderer
{
    private let A4PageWidth : Double = 595.2
private let A4PageHeight : Double = 841.8
private let leftPadding: CGFloat = 18.0;

override init()
{
    super.init()

    let pageFrame : CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: A4PageWidth, height: A4PageHeight)
...
```

Thank you

Comment: so far i understand apples Documentation, the app should switch automatically based on locale between the formats. Unfortunately this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you use the wrong rect when you calling the drawPage method for your pdfRenderer.

many examples shows something like this:

```
pdfRenderer.drawPage(at: i, in: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())
```

use rect for a A4 format instead of UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()

e.g. CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8)